# ECONNREFUSED with Postgres, what is wrong with my addresses?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, ubuntu-18.04

I have a cloud server (ubuntu 18.04) with NodeJS, postgresql, sequelize. My server starts, but cant connect to DB, i get
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.0.2:5432

If i run ss -tl

[tcp] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQV6s.png)

and here is the sequilize.js

```
export default new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME, 
    process.env.DB_USER, 
    process.env.DB_PASS, 
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 5432,
        define: {
            underscored: true
        },
        logging: false,
        timezone: 'Europe',
    }
)
```

I am new to linux, sorry, got confused. I tried to switch host in sequilize to 192.168.0.2, the error is the same. How do i fix this?

Comment: did you try `localhost:5432` or `127.0.0.1:5432` ?

Comment: Your postgres is misconfigured, it does not accept connections from localhost. Check pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: @freakish It does. It listens on 127.0.0.1. As suggested by Niralfasi try to connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or configure to also listen on 192.168.0.2

Comment: @Tarik ECONNREFUSED literally means that there is no one listening on the other side. Plus OP clearly tries to connect to 127.0.0.1, so I have no idea what you are talking about. Also, how exactly you know that his postgres is correctly configured?

Comment: @freakish when i try to go to /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf. it says "bash: etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf: No such file or directory".  Tried to get there both from root and postgres user. I run psql postgres -c "show hba_file" and it shows the path from previous that i tried to enter. Also says (1 row). Cant figure out why that happens

Comment: @chipikov_m you said you have "cloud server", does it mean VPS? Did you install postgres by yourself? On the same VPS? If so, then you have something seriously messed up with the environment.

Comment: @freakish yes, VPS. I installed with sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib, and then basically did nothing else. Yes, it is on the same VPS. Any suggestions where to look? Googling didn't help

Comment: Since the error says 192.168.0.2 but the code fragment says 127.0.0.1, i would say you have some other code which is actually causing the problem; and what you showed is being overridden, or ignored, or isn't even the right file to start with.

Comment: @freakish Look at the OP screenshot. Postgres is listening on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Tarik well, either the screenshot is wrong, or the code is wrong, or there is some firewall in-between (which would be insanely weird for a localhost setup) or actually db and the code run on different networks/machines.

Comment: Code and DB probably on different machines and obviously not accessible via 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this it is always a good idea to try to connect with some tool that is known to work to make sure that you can indeed reach that port on that IP from your host, and that the database server responds and works.

For Postgres, there is a command line tool called `psql` that you can use:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U $DB_USER $DB_NAME
```

You can use any other CLI or GUI tool that can connect to Postgres, but make sure that it is run locally on the same host as your Node app is running.

If you cannot connect in that way, then your Node app would not connect as well.

As freakish already noticed in the comments, your database may not accept connections from localhost. If you verify that this is the case, check the configuration, in particular: `listen_addresses`

See the documentation:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES

Comment: including new comments above, managed to get to pg_hba.conf through nano "the file location" from postgres user. Changed the line 
*# IPv4 local connections:*
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
to "trust". Then got to the postgresql.conf file, tried listen_adresses="*" and then tried "localhost, 192.168.0.2".  Error is the same. 
Everything worked on my computer locally, now i am renting VPS (says its IP is 192.168.0.2), transferred all there, and cannot connect :)

Comment: btw command from your answer with host 127.0.0.1 shows SSL connection, with 192.168.0.2 connection refused